# Cannot open .sqlproj because it is not supported

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sqlproj

I have inherited a VS2010 project that includes a .SQLPROJ.

I'm not having any problems with the .csproj. But I am having a problem opening the .SQLPROJ in the solution. When I try to open the .SQLPROJ, I get the following error:

```
MyDBProject.sqlproj cannot be opened because its project type (.sqlproj) is not supported by this version of the application. To open it, please use a version that supports this type of project.
```

It's my understanding that this solution was developed using VS2010. But I can't open the DB project. Is there software that needs installed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`.sqlproj` stands for a SQL Server Data Tools project, you can download the tools [**here**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh297027)

Comment: Data Tools for VS2010 is no longer available at this link but can still be downloaded if you have an MSDN subscription. The installation will fail with a certificate error, though. I was able to install it after setting the system date back to something before 10/6/2013 (see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ssdt/archive/2013/10/08/known-issue-ssdt-install-fails-validating-certificates.aspx)

Comment: For the same scenario for VS2012, same tool is required, [reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18148445/cannot-open-sqlproj-because-it-is-not-supported)