# Unsupported This version of Visual Studio is unable to open the following projects

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

I'm getting error like this after updating sql server to 2016. I have opened the project in **VS2015** & while rebuilding **Database** project I'm getting error like below:

> Unsupported
>   This version of Visual Studio is unable to open the following projects. The project types may not be installed or this version of Visual Studio may not support them. 
>   For more information on enabling these project types or otherwise migrating your assets, please see the details in the "Migration Report" displayed after clicking OK.[image]

Comment: Since I didn't upgrade to 2016 by now I am not sure, but maybe you have to do some additional installation? Such as Data Tools 2016 or something? By the way, in which VS did you create the project initially?

Comment: Install Sql Server Data Tools. Similar question to this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18148445/cannot-open-sqlproj-because-it-is-not-supported

Comment: @Tyron78 I have created project in vs 2015 and currently using same

Comment: Then it is most certainly that you need to install / update the SQL Server Data Tools - they are dependent on the SQL Server Version

Answer (score 31):

I got the same error when opening Old (VS2015) project on **Visual Studio 2017**

These actions solved my problem:

- Install the [latest version of SSDT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt?view=sql-server-2017)
- Open Visual Studio 2017: Go to: Tools > Extensions And Updates > Search: Microsoft Integration Services Projects > Click: Enable
- In SSIS Project On Solution: Right Click > Reload Project

Comment: Are you still able to open the project with VS2015 after successfully opening in VS2017, or does it convert the project? Some on our team haven't upgraded yet.

Comment: just adding that this solution also work for studio 2019

Comment: @StefanosZilellis I can't find `Microsoft Integration Services Projects` in Extensions --> Manage Extensions in VS2019.

Comment: @xinthose not sure why, try the text search perhaps?

Comment: If anyone wondering its called _SQL Server Data Tools - Sql Editor_ in VS 2022. At least that's what I had to enable. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: It isn't working in my case. I tried install and enable it from Extensions but doesn't work.

Answer (score 5):

I got the same error when opening old projects in Visual Studio 2019.

These actions solved my problem:

Open Visual Studio 2019 and go to `Tools > Extensions > Download` to download these three tools:

1. SQL Server Integration Services Project
2. Microsoft reporting service project
3. Microsoft analysis service project

Close VS and update package, then restart VS by double-click an old .sln file.

Comment: All I had to enable was _SQL Server Data Tools - Sql Editor_ in VS 2022.

Comment: It isn't working in my case. I tried install and enable it from Extensions but doesn't work.

Answer (score -4):

- Uninstall all SQL Data Tools from Programs and Features
- Uninstall Analysis Services and Reporting Services
- Install SSDT for Visual Studio from Microsoft website
- Right click Visual Studio solution file and 'Open With' MS Visual Studio 2017
- Right click and choose 'Reload Project'