# ERROR: This version of Visual Studio is unable to open the following projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools

Today, when I opened my Visual Studio Enterprise to work, the packages were having issues.

[image]

I tried uninstalling Visual Studio and reinstalling it, and I did the same with SQL Server Data Tools, but nothing worked. Can somebody help me? I didn't update anything yesterday, and this error seems very strange in this context.

Comment: We can't really help you if you cover-up the important parts of the error message...

Comment: What does your `.sln` file look like. What kind of project is it complaining about? What version and edition of Visual Studio is this about?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] - note that we don't care about your actual projects/code we need **sample** code that shows the problem (and limited to just the problem). This will also allow you to post complete images/text of all error messages without blacking out potentially useful information.

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusing messages. I found the error!

The issue was with "SQL Server Integration Services." I uninstalled and reinstalled it, and it is now fixed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. We do not write answers here that "find the bug"; we require a **specific** question - which will come out of your best attempt to [understand](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/) and [locate](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05) a specific problem, and showcase it in a [mre]. A question that is suitable for Stack Overflow is one where you have already figured out the **specific part** of the code that does something different from what you expect (and you should concretely *expect something*), and don't understand why.

Comment: @Ferri16 Hi, I posted an answer based on your comment. You can mark it so that it can help more people.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please do not obscure important information when posting questions.

There is a post similar to yours here: [Unsupported This version of Visual Studio is unable to open the following projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45613218/unsupported-this-version-of-visual-studio-is-unable-to-open-the-following-projec).

This issue usually occurs when using Visual Studio to open projects created based on other versions of Visual Studio. Your error should belong to the sqlserver class.

Your method of reinstalling "SQL Server Integration Services" is correct, or updating it to the latest version can usually solve this issue.