# SSIS Unit-test not run well (incompatible)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, ssis, xunit

I tried find and use a open source framework for **start BI project** with TDD .

I choose [SSISUNIT](https://github.com/johnwelch/ssisUnit) for step one. ssisUnit is a unit testing framework for SQL Server Integration Services. It is loosely based on the xUnit family of unit testing frameworks, but is tailored to better support the SSIS environment.

Download [SSISUNIT](https://github.com/johnwelch/ssisUnit) project and run solution 2017 in VS. But I've error when sln open.

Problem :

[image]

[image]

[image]

I tried :

- Install the latest version of SSDT recommendation ([in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18148445/cannot-open-sqlproj-because-it-is-not-supported))
  I have SQL Server Integration Services Project, Microsoft reporting service project, Microsoft analysis service project

[image]

- Read [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45613218/unsupported-this-version-of-visual-studio-is-unable-to-open-the-following-projec) but not worked for me in vs 2019.
- I tried changed the Project platform to x86,x64 and AnyCPU.

> We use SQL-SERVER 2019 SSIS SSAS(MDX), Visual Studio 2019, Power BI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to remove or unload that project from the solution. Microsoft deprecated support for the setup projects.

Comment: Thanks Mr.Welch ,  Compatibility problem is solve, but I can't  run  well, and have 49new error about *missing assembly reference* , I tried Colne git repository and not worked. do you have new version of project in .Net framework  4 or above ? I feel that the problem is with .Net version 2, which has expired. Am I going the wrong way at all? I got confused.